# x-11 display issue: Trying to run gparted on a different box and it keeps complaining it can't open the display; how do I track / fix this?

Tags: linux, display, xorg, fedora-38

I must be overlooking something small and silly, or something on the user's end (what I think of as client-side) has changed because ... for a LONG time - 20 years or more - I've been managing a site's servers scattered in various racks from a system in my office.

What's changed is that I used to use a Windows box and would run linux / unix utilities like `gparted` via `cygwin`, which provides an x server and it worked fine (plus the `cygwin` terminal is a LOT more friendly than any x-term I've yet found). ...The day finally came (over the weekend) when I had to retire my old Windows 7 box, switching to Linux, and try as I might, I keep getting:

```
(gpartedbin:52444): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:20:10.330: cannot open display: 123.some.ip:0
```

I tried all the usual stuff, including:

```
$ xhost +

$ export DISPLAY=123.some.ip:0
```

And, since it's an internal net, even:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

just to be sure that wasn't it!

So far, no joy.

I DO note that my new "office user interface system" (the new linux box) thinks its local display is just :0 so that's not really helpful. ... If it matters, it's `Fedora 38`, a unique hybrid of Server and Workstation but mostly all standard packages, just an odd mix of 'em.

Though it wasn't frequent, I KNOW I've done this sort of thing quite easily when I had to on older versions of `Fedora`, `Debian`, etc, and don't recall anything special to do.

Could it be the modern `x-11` needs some kind of "pay attention to external connections!" kind of hint, similar to how `Cygwin` needs you to tell it to listen to `TCP`? If so, IDK how to do that.

What am I missing?

(Note that for the time being, I've had to borrow a laptop that's running `Cygwin` on top of windows and both `gparted` and `gnome-disks` came right up - of course! ...It HAS to be something simple!)

Answer (score 1):

After perhaps more than two day's time lost, I figured it out.

The shortest of short answer is: I wasn't using X-11, even though I was sure I was! The longer explanation follows.

I don't have a fully comprehensive answer regarding when certain changes happened, but as of NOW, `Fedora 38`:

Somewhere along the way, `Fedora's Workstation Desktop`, which I installed over Server to get a somewhat familiar windowing system, switched from `Xorg` to something called `Wayland`.

`Wayland`, for whatever - in my view misguided - reason, think's using displays on another system is a security risk and disables the "remote display" capability by default, and they don't tell you how to turn it back on.

Exactly how to turn it back on is now behind a paywall at Red Hat's web site (I lost the link to prove it during one of the many session restarts), however, in reading the [various materials about Wayland,](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/system-administrators-guide/Wayland/) there's an open admission that "there are still applications and behaviors that don't work as expected," including, apparently, this important feature of `X11`.

My solution was:

During login, click the cog-wheel type logo and select running one of the two original `X-11` (AKA `Xorg`) options, and then continue as normal. You can still get caught up in firewall and `xhost` permissions - and maybe even `SELinux` - but above I indicated I'd taken those things out of the way.

Thus, once free of `Wayland`, "It Just Works!" ... Time to celebrate! And, HEY developers of `Wayland`, MAYBE you ought to TELL us stuff like this, perhaps HOW to overcome this one via commented out options in the config file?

Comment: Wayland is the future, or so I keep being told. I don't know about RedHat, but you can disable it on Debian GNU/Linux: https://wiki.debian.org/GDM#Disabling_Wayland